# Postgres numeric type overflow after 1023 bisection of 1

Tags: postgresql, datatypes

i am testing the numeric type in postgres according the precision and scale i declared the numeric type with (1000,900) which gives me 900 digits decimal points but when i test it by inserting and halving 1 it stops after the 1023 halving and throws the error: ERROR:  value out of range: overflow
SQL state: 22003.

I use this statement to insert:

```
 insert into numeric_test 
  select   ((1 / power(2, i))::numeric)+10000000, pg_column_size(( 1/power(2, i)::numeric)+10000000)
from generate_series(1, 1024) as i;
```

And that is my table:

```
create table numeric_test (
  pos numeric(1000,900),
  sz integer
);

alter table numeric_test add column index_x integer;
```

Is there a limit how big and numeric type entry could get? The size of the 102 3iteration is 127 bytes and the 1024 iteration throws an error of overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numeric(1000,900)` column has nothing to do with it; the `select` alone produces the overflow error.

Calling `power()` with integer arguments will default to the floating-point version of the function. `power(2,1024)` is causing the overflow, as the maximum [base-2 double-precision exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding) is 1023.

There is also a version of `power()` which takes `numeric` arguments, and will handle 2<sup>1024</sup> without overflowing. If you cast your inputs to `numeric`, it will call this version instead:

```
select ((1 / power(2, i::numeric)))+10000000, pg_column_size(( 1/power(2, i::numeric))+10000000)
from generate_series(1, 1024) as i;
```